# How can I display last property in a JSON object first in the UI

Tags: json, angular, object

I have a JSON of following format:

```
[
{Details: [{name: "WII", type:"Video Games", id:"lint"}]
]
```

however on the UI in a table, I want to display ID first in the first column followed by the others.

Comment: Not a valid JSON!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume this is your JS data structure:

```
let list = [
  { Details: [{ name: "WII", type: "Video Games", id: "lint" }] }
];
```

Then in your Angular component template:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of list" >
    <td>{{item.Details[0].id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Details[0].name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Details[0].type}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Of course, this is not ideal but to give you a better answer/solution you should provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Pipe to get the keys and reverse it.

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys.reverse();
  }
}
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oypjtx?file=app/keys.pipe.ts)